# Script to search for value in whole sheet and delete based on it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wanted to make a script that searches 9 specified sheets in the whole spreadsheet for the value of four cells next to each other, and when it finds it, it deletes the value from only the last cell it found.

Example:

Input part:

```
data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 |
-------------------------------
 ABC  |  123  |  XYZ  |  MNO  |
-------------------------------
 [Search and destroy button]
```

The four data values would be searched in the sheets that look like this where is should be found and deleted:

```
       A      B      C       D     E    F       G       H      I    
1  |data1 | data2 |data3 | data4 |   |data1 | data2 |data3 | data4 |
2  |------|-------|------|-------|---|------|-------|------|-------|
3  | gfd  | nbv   | hgf  | hjg   |   | sdg  | uzt   | saf  | hdd   |
4  |------|-------|------|-------|---|------|-------|------|-------|
5  | ztr  | mvb   | ABC  | jgf   |   | uzt  | XYZ   | XYZ  | ABC   |
6  |------|-------|------|-------|---|------|-------|------|-------|
7  | ioj  | lkj   | gfd  | jgf   |   | ABC  | 123   | XYZ  | MNO   |
8  |------|-------|------|-------|---|------|-------|------|-------|
9  | mnb  | ztd   | jgf  | gfd   |   | nfs  | tez   | hfd  | xyv   |
10 |------|-------|------|-------|---|------|-------|------|-------|
```

In this case it would need to find the data thats from F7 to I7 and delete the value from I7.

Is this possible? Its a little more advanced then what im capable of figuring out unfortunately.

**Edit:**
This is what i was able to come up with that works as i wanted it to. I have to specify the Sheet names, but its not a problem i can get that from the data anyway.

```
function SaF() {


var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss = sh.getActiveSheet();
var cell = ss.getRange('A1:D1');
var value = cell.getValues();
var shname = ss.getRange('Q9').getValue();                        

var sheets = sh.getSheetByName(shname)

  var activeR = cell.getRow()-1;
  var activeC = cell.getColumn()-1;
  var data = sheets.getRange("A1:BS87").getValues()
  var step = 0

  for(var r=activeR;r<data.length;++r){
    for(var c=activeC;c<data[0].length;++c){
      step++
      Logger.log(step+' -- '+value[0]+'  =  '+data[r][c]);
      if(data[r][c]==''||step==1){ continue };
      if(value[0][0]==data[r][c] && value[0][1]==data[r][c+1] && value[0][2]==data[r][c+2] && value[0][3]==data[r][c+3]){
         sheets.getRange(r+1,c+4).clearContent();
        return;
      }        
    }
  }
 }
```

Its probably not very clean, and could be made better like:

- I cant specify a source thats not from A1, i suspect this is cause of the way it looks up rows and columns, but dont have the knowhow to change it.

Comment: You can use an inner loop an outer loop in the Outerloop you can iterate through all of the sheets and access them by putting all of their names in an array and using getSheetsByName() and in the inner loop you can access the same range and iterate through it row by row getting data and deciding what to delete. Try to use getValues() rather than getValue() as much as possible

Comment: Can it be the case that `ABC  |  123  |  XYZ  |  MNO` are located in other cells say `A3:D3` or in the mentioned cells only?

Comment: @Madhurjya Yes it could be anywhere, also the actual sheets that the search would look at would be multiple columns of 4 not just two.

Comment: If it could anywhere then you will have search everywhere.?  You could possibly use `textFinder`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

The parameter keyA is a flat array equal to the values of the adjacent cells that you are searching for.  I assume adjacent cells are in same row.

```
function searchAndDestroy(keyA) {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getDataRange();
  const vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length-keyA.length+1;j++) {
      if(vA[i][j]==keyA[0] && vA[i][j+1]==keyA[1] && vA[i][j+2]==keyA[2] && vA[i][j+3]==keyA[33]) {
        sh.getRange(i+1,j+4).setValue('');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I couldnt get this to works, it gives me an error that length is not defined, im geuessing "keyA" has to be defined somehow, but if i just gave it a range where the data that i want it to use for the search it just doesnt do anything. From what i can gather from looking at the code, is it only running on the current active sheet? and doesnt go into other sheets?

Comment: Yes as I said in the opening lines if is a flattend array.  It is what you are searching for.

Comment: Im sorry for not understanding, i dont have much background on codeing like this just what i gathered for projects i needed at the time. Heres how my understanding lacks: "keyA"(i dont know where the value for this comes from, maybe im using the function wrong with a button?). "ss/sh/rg/vg" (all just get the values from the single active sheet that im looking at?), "for..."(first makes strings the size for keyA? and after that checks ita against keyA if they match). What i still dont get is how i determain keyA(A1:D1 currently). Should i make a var for it? but that didnt work the first time.